# Multiple Kafka Consumers in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, consumer

So i am running kafka with two topics and they will both be serving files -

Topic 1 - I am reading the string value from it and processing it.
Topic 2 - I need the binary values for processing.

So i am guessing i would need two consumers? 
The reasoning behind this is that in the properties for the data from first topic i need a StringSerializer/Deserializer and for the second one i need a BinaryArraySerializer Desererializer.

So is it feasible to have two consumer implementations?

I know what I can get the string value and convert it to binary or vice versa but somehow having two consumers seems to be the clean way of doing it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are using spring you can set the serializer at @KafkaListener(properties = {"key-deserializer:<<serializer_class_name>>","key-deserializer:<<serializer_class_name>>"}. so for two different topics you can have two different @KafkaListener annotation with different serializer classes